# UK citizenship language requirements

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship, language-test

I just got the PR and was considering whether to apply for UK citizenship. My question is about the language tests that I am supposed to perform. I work as a university lecturer, and part of my duties are to teach in English and write papers in English. I am also a fellow of the Higher Education Academy. Will any of this help me waive the language requirement or not?

Comment: No, but the qualifications you used to get that job may fulfill the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

[The UK guidance](https://www.gov.uk/english-language/exemptions) sets forth those do not need to prove their knowledge of English for citizenship (and setting):

> **Who doesn't need to prove their knowledge of English**
>
> You don’t need to prove your knowledge of English if you’re:
>
> - aged 65 or over
> - unable to, because of a long-term physical or mental condition
>
> You must provide a completed exemption form or letter from a doctor confirming your physical or mental condition.
>
> **Nationalities that are exempt**
>
> You won’t need to prove your knowledge of English if you’re a citizen of:
>
> - Antigua and Barbuda
> - Australia
> - The Bahamas
> - Barbados
> - Belize
> - Canada
> - Dominica
> - Grenada
> - Guyana
> - Jamaica
> - New Zealand
> - Republic of Ireland (for citizenship only)
> - St Kitts and Nevis
> - St Lucia
> - St Vincent and the Grenadines
> - Trinidad and Tobago
> - USA
>
> If you’re from a country that’s not on the list you’ll need to prove your knowledge of English, even if English is an official language.
>
> **If you’re applying for citizenship**
>
> ***There are no other exemptions if you’re applying to become a British citizen. You must have a relevant English language qualification even if you were exempt when you were granted settlement.*** *
>
> **Exemptions if you’re applying to settle**
>   You don’t need to prove your knowledge of English if you’re applying as:
>
> - a victim of domestic violence as the partner or spouse of a British citizen or someone settled in the UK
> - the partner or spouse of a person who has died who was either a British citizen or someone settled in the UK
> - an adult dependent relative between 18 and 64 of someone who is present and settled in the UK, is a refugee or has humanitarian protection
> - a refugee living in the UK
> - someone living in the UK with discretionary leave
> - someone living in the UK for with humanitarian protection
> - someone who has permission to stay in the UK as a retired person of independent means
> - a Commonwealth citizen on discharge from HM Forces, including Gurkhas
> - a highly skilled migrant applying under the terms of the highly skilled migrant program (HSMP) judicial review and your dependants
> - someone in exceptional circumstances, eg as an orphan, widow or over-age dependant

***Added emphasis mine*** *

> [Approved English language qualifications](https://www.gov.uk/english-language/approved-english-language-qualifications)
>
> You can prove your knowledge of English by having a [recognised English test qualification](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-applying-for-uk-visa-approved-english-language-tests) from an approved test centre.
>
> You need to have a certificate to prove you have the qualification, or be able to view your results online.
>
> [If your degree was taught or researched in English](https://www.gov.uk/english-language/degrees-in-english)
>
> You can prove your knowledge of English by having a degree that was taught or researched in English.
>
> If you have a degree from a UK university, you only need your original degree certificate.
>   If your degree isn’t from a UK university, you’ll need your original degree certificate and one of the following:
>
> - an original letter or certificate from [UK NARIC](http://www.naric.org.uk/visas%20and%20nationality/) confirming the equivalent level of your degree, plus an official letter from your university with your name and degree confirming that your degree was taught in English
> - an original and official certificate from your university confirming the degree was taught or researched in a majority English-speaking country (except Canada)

Comment: You might want to add the bit from page 4 that allows people with certain academic qualifications to use those to prove their English competency instead of having to take a test.